# Unable to push to Heroku, failed to compile chromedriver app

Tags: selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

All of a sudden I am unable to push my code to Heroku via `git push heroku master`.
This is the error that I'm getting:

```
remote: Archive:  /tmp/chromedriver.zip
remote:   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
remote:   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
remote:   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
remote:   the last disk(s) of this archive.
remote: unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/chromedriver.zip or
remote:         /tmp/chromedriver.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/chromedriver.zip.ZIP, period.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile chromedriver app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

The buildpacks I am using are heroku/python, https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome, and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver. I am using the Selenium ChromeDriver in my app. My app is running on one worker dyno. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your problem is due to the same thing, but I was getting the same issue as you because of an invalid CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION config.

In my case I had set my heroku config variable CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION to an
invalid version:

```
110.0.5481.177
```

when the correct version was:

```
110.0.5481.77
```

I would take another look at what you set the version to and see if it's invalid as well.